# cpp.obj files are not being regenerated when a ui file is edited

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, cmake, ninja

I'm trying to build a Qt project using Ninja, MSVC 2019, and CMake.

The problem I'm facing is the following:

When I make changes to a UI file and rebuild the project, the `ui_mainwindow.h` file is regenerated, but not the `mainwindow.cpp.obj` file.

As a result, when I run the application, the modifications do not appear on the screen.

I'm new to this configuration (MSVC 2019 + Ninja). Previously, I built my project using NMake and MSVC 2019, and I didn't encounter this problem.

However, the build process was taking too long. That's why I switched to Ninja, but now I need to figure out why Ninja is not regenerating the `cpp.obj` files.

CMakeFile.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(NinjaTest VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)


qt_add_executable(NinjaTest
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )

target_link_libraries(NinjaTest PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

set_target_properties(NinjaTest PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

install(TARGETS NinjaTest
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(NinjaTest)
endif()
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>260</x>
      <y>260</y>
      <width>63</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>COUCOU</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>280</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>83</width>
      <height>29</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2):

I update my CMake to 3.26.4 versions and add to CMakeList.txt file :

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC OFF)
file(GLOB_RECURSE ui_files "*.ui"); 
qt6_wrap_ui(WRAPPED_UI_FILES ${ui_files}); 
add_executable(NinjaTest2
                main.cpp
                mainwindow.cpp
                mainwindow.h
                ${WRAPPED_UI_FILES} );
```

Everything works now